# How do I get a certificate on a server from a certificate authority server using an OpenSSL request?

Tags: linux, centos, openssl, certificates

How do I get a successful request for a certificate from one Linux server to a Linux server that is a certificate authority?  I'm using Centos 7 on both servers on the network.  I'm using an OpenSSL version from January 2013 on each server.

My /etc/ssh/sshd_config file on both Linux servers is configured to allow ports 22, 443, 8140, and 61610.  I tested these ports being open with ssh -p commands so there are no firewall issues stopping me.  I ran openssl s_client -connect :8140 --showcerts

The output showed this:

```
...
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 5 bytes and written 0 bytes.
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session
...
```

The server that I ran it on needs to get a certificate on the remote server.  Other commands leading up to this post brought me to this point.  I have a Linux server that needs a certificate for my project.  It isn't working.

How do I interpret this output to ensure OpenSSL is working?  I can SSH between the machines. But problems arising from my separate project lead me to believe that OpenSSL isn't configured properly.

Can two Linux servers use SSH when different versions of OpenSSL are installed in each of them?  I have tried the openssl command above when both versions were the exactly same.  I also tried a newer version of OpenSSL on one server.

Comment: If a port, here apparently 8410, is served by `sshd`, it is using the SSH protocol. You can only connect to that port using the SSH protocol, such as the `ssh` program. The OpenSSL package, and the `openssl` program, implement the SSL/TLS protocol which is a different protocol and cannot connect to a port of a program running the SSH protocol like `sshd`. Different versions of SSL/TLS are upward compatible, and there is only one version of SSH currently in use, different variants of which are compatible, but no version of SSL/TLS is compatible with SSH.

Comment: My testing suggests that this isn't true.  I did some basic OpenSSL commands.  I think you mean port 8140.

Comment: Yes I mistyped your port number. I assume(d) by 'sshd_config ... allow ports' you meant adding/changing `Port` values in sshd_config. If so, sshd listens on those ports and accepts connections using SSH protocol only. `openssl s_client` does not do SSH protocol, period full stop. I don't know what you did do unless you give specifics, but I'll bet $100 right now you can't connect to sshd with `openssl s_client` (unless you've completely replaced the source of openssl/apps/s_client.c).